# How do I hide the "Register" link after user successfully logs in?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

A user opens our web app and is automatically taken to the default page.

While on default page, if the user has not logged in or created an account, the `Register or Login` link is displayed at the top of the page.

```
 <table bgcolor="#003366" width="100%">
  <tr><td align="right"><a href="login.aspx"><span style=" color:darkOrange;font-weight:bold">Login or Register</span></a></td></tr></table>
```

This is fine.

However, after user successfully logged in, s/he is redirected to his/her page.

The problem is that the user clicks the default page for whatever reason, the `Register or Log in` link appears again.

Is there a way to hide this link as long as the user is logged in and only show it after the user logs off?

Thanks in advance for your help.

This is the change I made so far, added label control:

```
 <table bgcolor="#003366" width="100%">
  <tr><td align="right"><a href="login.aspx"><span style=" color:darkOrange;font-weight:bold"><label id="loginId" runat="server" Text="Login / Register"></label></span></a></td></tr></table>
```

Comment: What kind of membership provider are you using?

Comment: `bgcolor`? `align="right"`? Inline styles? You need a web designer, stat.

Comment: @millimoose What has a web designer got to do with client side development?

Comment: @TimBJames It was a tangent. I was pointing out the terrible practice when it comes to doing the layout.

Comment: @Kenny The basic idea is that you add the attributes `runat="server" Visible="<%# !IsLoggedIn #>"` to whatever you want hidden and databind on the first page load / after stuff changes. Where `IsLoggedIn` is a property in your codebehind that determines whether the user is or is not logged in. That or give the element an `ID` and set this property from codebehind directly. You can do this for any HTML element, not just ASP.NET controls.

Comment: @millimoose Indeed in-line styling is terrible! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the fact that your link is pointing to a `login.aspx` page, I can see that you are probably using the Web Forms section of asp.net

Usually when working with Authentication and showing/hiding elements on a page within Web Forms, you can make use of some asp.net controls.

If you are using the build in .net Membership provider, then there is a control called the [Login View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295194.aspx). This is a simple control that allows you to show different content when a user is Logged in/out.

You can do something as simple as this;

```
<asp:loginview ID="Loginview1" runat="server">
    <AnonymousTemplate>
        <a href="Login.aspx">Login / Register</a>
    </AnonymousTemplate>
    <LoggedInTemplate>
        <a href="Logout.aspx">Logout</a>
    </LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:loginview>
```

This will automatically show/hide the correct content.

You can also make use of any server side control and using the `Visible` property of this. So in your code you can set controls to be visible or not depending on the logged in status.

Also you could wrap your code within a `<asp:Panel>` then just show hide depending;

```
<asp:Panel id="pnlLoggedOut" runat="server" Visible="True">
    <a href="login.aspx"><span style=" color:darkOrange;font-weight:bold">Login or Register</span></a>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel id="pnlLoggedIn" runat="server" Visible="False">
    <a href="logout.aspx"><span style=" color:darkOrange;font-weight:bold">Logout</span></a>
</asp:Panel>
```

In your code behind you can show either or.

Another way is to just have your `<a>` tag as a server control. You can then update the text and hyper link depending on the logged in status.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlLoginStatus" runat="server" NavigateUrl="Login.aspx" Text="Login / Register" />
```

In your code behind if the user is logged in, then you can change the `NavigateUrl` and the `Text` property.

Comment: Just to be sure, @Tim, the pnLoggedOut, pnLoggedIn worked for me.

The reason it wasn't working earlier was I didn't include the Handles in pageLoad() event --- Handles Me.Load did the trick.

Thanks a lot

Comment: @Kenny Glad I could be of help. I hate it when you miss the `Handles Me.Load` event! Always sitting there wondering why the code isn't working! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain your code, as much as possible, then I recommend wrapping your markup with a control that can be accessed server-side, like this:

```
<asp:Panel id="PanelLogin" runat="server" Visible="True">
    <table bgcolor="#003366" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="right">
                <a href="login.aspx"><span style=" color:darkOrange;font-weight:bold">Login or Register</span></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Panel>
```

Now in your code-behind `Page_Load` event, you can check to see if the user has logged in or not. I suggest you store whether or not they are logged in cache (i.e. `Session` value `IsLoggedOn`). You will toggle the visibility of the ASP.NET `Panel`, based upon the value of `IsLoggedOn`, like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool isUserLoggedOn = (bool)Session["IsLoggedOn"];

    if(isUserLoggedOn)
    {
        PanelLogin.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        PanelLogin.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when the user logins upon successful login. you should keep his username in Session as

```
Session["user"] = username;

Now on page Load() check if Session["user"] is null then label.text = "register"
else = label.text = "";
```

hope it will help.

Comment: Great stuff great people. @Karl, I tried your solution but didn't work. This means that nothing changed. I was still getting the Register link when I click on Default page. Maybe, I am missing something in the code? Khalid, when I tried your solution, I no longer see Register whether logged in or not. One thing I noticed though was the when I tried Label.Tex, I was getting an error. It kept giving me the option of label.InnerText. Maybe that's why it didn't work. Tim, I am not using loginView, sorry but nice piece of code though.

I updated my code. Did I use label incorrectly?

Comment: Cany you use asp.net Linkbutton instead of <a>.if you can use then you can change its text proper according the if() in my solution .

Comment: well may asp.net's Linkbutton or Hyperlink can be an alternatives and then programmatically any thing can be done with that.

Comment: @Kenny Checkout my updated answer for alternatives to LoginView. Also why are you against the LoginView?

Comment: @Tim, so I can try to panel option and then use something similar to Karl's code on pageload?

Comment: @Tim, I am not against it.

You said it is used with membership provider and I am not using membership provider. So, I don't know if it will work without membership provider. Please see my previous response.

Comment: @Kenny, well it works with FormsAuthentication, which you can set with what ever provider you are using. You just need to call `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("username", True)` This will then work.

Comment: The think is that @Karl's code looks very good but I can't see the Login/Register when I use just the markup alone.

Tim, I must be doing something wrong but yours isn't working either.

When I try the Loginview code and I use the formsAutentication..., all I see is Logout.

This is frustrating.